# Facebook "Like it" button localization using Microsoft.Web.Helpers

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I've implemented "Like" button on my page using Microsoft.Web.Helpers. It is however in English. How can I change it to be Polish for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the locale.  There is a locale in the path in the Javascript SDK's URL.

Most examples use `en_US` for the locale:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId={appid}";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

So you will need to replace that with your locale.

For more information please read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: I've generated the facebook like button from facebook website. Then I simply added a partial View with this button

Comment: Yes, by copying and pasting the code from the facebook website, it will default the local to en_US.  You will need to change it to your locale.

Comment: Are you sure there's not more than one loading of the framework?  Can you share a link where the like button is in english even though you specified polish?

Comment: it's obviously not english even though I specified polish. You can generate the button here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Can you share the link to your site that has the malfunctioning like button?

Comment: Then could you please click view source in your browser and paste the HTML in your question.

Comment: How did you change to Polish?

Comment: I generated the button like here: developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like and then implemented it as a partial view

Comment: That's exactly what I asked you to do in my answer, is it not?